# Is EOS coin required to run private blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, coin

I am new to EOSIO, I leart that NETWORK, CPU and RAM can be purchased by EOS coin. The question is if I build a private blockchain and do I still need EOS coin to purchase these resources?

Answer (score 1):

No. A private eosio blockchain will have it's own token to use for resource allocation.

You can check more information on the developers documentation here:
https://developers.eos.io/

Comment: thanks, any doc / link to address this?

Comment: Updated with the link for documentation...

Comment: haha, thanks my friend. The link I am after is the part which clearly addressing private eosio blockchain is not using formal eos coin. I have looked through https://developers.eos.io/ but did not see that part.

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence  tutorial it may help you to understand it better.